# capacitor ios & android: release different assets for phone vs. tablet

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, google-play-console

This seems like a reasonably common use case, I am wondering why I could not find an answer to this quesiton.

CapacitorJS:
I want to release a different ipa/apk for phones vs tablet.

My app is an offline app. It contains extremely many images.

I realize that the images should be way bigger on ipad, roughly 4x the file size. I want to keep my phone bundle size as minimal as possible. For the ipad bundle size I dont care too much, as iPads are usually connected to WIFI so the dowlonad bundle size is not that crucial there.

How do I do that? I realize that this is probably not a Capacitor question but rather a question about IOS & Android development. I would probably create different build processes for the phone & tablet versions, different `ionic cap sync` commands or so, right? But then how do I tell the app stores which bundle should be used for phones/tablets?

My app is 100 MB with compressed images currently. The size for tablets can be 400 MB, I don't care. The 100 MB bundle images look pixelated on tablets currently.

I do not want to use a service that downloads the images later as it should be 100% offline, to save myself money & time for hosting of course.

What are some possible solutions to this problem?

#### EDIT:

I came up with one possible solution:

although not perfect: I could release the same app twice but once give it the name "`<AppName>` HD". But is this legal in terms of app store policies, to have such identical apps only differing in image resolution? I have seen many app examples that are almost the same, like kids versions for example. Maybe someone could confirm that this is legal before I try to submit it to app store review?